# React-Native. TouchableOpacity works only when tap with 2 fingers

Tags: ios, react-native, native-base

I'm running my app via React-Native and native-base and I got some problems with component TouchableOpacity.

When I'm writing my component like

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPress()}}>
    <Text>Some text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity
```

It works perfect, when I tap with 1 finger

But when I'm running like this - My Code:

```
renderList () {
    return (
        <List>
            {this.state.data.map( ( restaurant, index ) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                        this.onPress();
                    }} key={index}>
                        <View style={styles.example}>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: 'Image URL' }}/>
                                <Body>
                                <Text>{restaurant.title}</Text>
                                <Text note>{restaurant.shortDescription}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </ListItem>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            } )}
        </List>

    );
}
```

It is ignoring 1 tap, twice tap etc, it is only working when I tap with 2 fingers. Didn't find any info about this problem. May be some one know how to solve this?

Thanks

Added FullCode:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Container,
    Button,
    Header,
    Left,
    Icon,
    Body,
    Right,
    Text,
    Content,
    List,
    ListItem,
    Thumbnail
} from 'native-base';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Restaurants extends Component {

constructor ( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
        data: this.props.data
    };
}

onPress () {
    console.log( 'Hello' );
}

renderList () {
    return (
        <List>
            {this.state.data.map( ( restaurant, index ) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                        this.onPress();
                    }} key={index}>
                        <View style={styles.example}>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: 'Image URL' }}/>
                                <Body>
                                <Text>{restaurant.title}</Text>
                                <Text note>{restaurant.shortDescription}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </ListItem>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            } )}
        </List>

    );
}

render () {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header style={styles.header}>
                <Left>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon style={styles.header_icon} name="arrow-back"/>
                    </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                <Text>Ресторанны</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon style={styles.header_icon}     name="restaurant"/>
                    </Button>
                </Right>
            </Header>
            <Content>
                {this.renderList()}
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create( {
header: {
    backgroundColor: '#606dff'
},
header_icon: {
    color: 'black'
},
example: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
}
} );
```

Comment: `this.onPress()` is a method you created? Can you post the code of it?

Comment: onPress () {
        console.log( 'Hello' );
    }

Comment: just in case, can you try changing your function name? Something like onItemPress()

Comment: @soutot, still the same.
I just need to hold 1 finger on my Row and click on this Row with the second finger, in this case it works

Comment: I don't remember of facing any issue like this. We can try debugging it a little. Try to remove each item from your `<ListItem>` component, for each item you remove, reload and try to tap it again. If all items are removed and the issue keeps the same, we can take a look at other components. Maybe something inside of it is conflicting.

Comment: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            this.onItemPress();
                        }} key={index}>
                            <View style={styles.example}>
                                <Text>hello</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: It is working without <ListItem>, probably it some bag of native-base

Comment: I'll post an answer, so you can read it better. Try it and let me know if worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we spoken, I'll post it here so it's better to read and copy the code.

Try this:

```
renderList() {
  return (
    <List>
      {
        this.state.data.map( ( restaurant, index ) => {
          return (
            <ListItem>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.onPress();
                }}
                key={index}
              >
                <View style={styles.example}>
                  <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: 'Image URL' }}/>
                  <Body>
                    <Text>{restaurant.title}</Text>
                    <Text note>{restaurant.shortDescription}</Text>
                  </Body>
                </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ListItem>
          );
        });
      }
    </List>
  );
}
```

I swapped `<ListItem>` and `<TouchableOpacity>`
There might be any conflict the way you wrote.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes, it is working, need to delete native-base and making via react-native only) Thank you)

Comment: Great. Glad to help

Comment: I just found that I can use onPress in <ListItem> component, so it is working fine without TouchableOpacity :D
Just you can use it like <ListItem onPress={......}>